# Group by date (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table

```
daten    name      sub   rate
*******************************
09.22  Jonh     some5      one
09.22  Jonh     some2      two
09.22  Jonh     some3      two
```

Need to get in html:

```
Jonh:
date some5 some2 some3
***********************
09.22 one  two   two
```

I do:

```
$str = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name= '$name' group by daten";
$rts = mysql_query($str);

echo "<h1>".$name."</h1>";
echo "<table border=\"1\"><th>date</th> "; 

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo  "<th>".$row['sub'] . "</th></tr>";
echo  "<tr><td>".$row['daten'] ."</td><td>".$row['rate']."</td></tr>";
     }
echo "</table>";
```

But such a code, when group by daten, displays only the first value. Without group all quite wrong.

Please tell me what is wrong and where to dig.

Thank you

Comment: Group by in absence of aggregate function will give you indeterminate row for each group

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid can you explain how in details? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to get all data in single row so you have to use if condition under your query. Mysql if  function returns a value based on a condition.  The syntex of IF is

```
if (expr, if_true_expr, if_false_expr)
```

If the expr evaluates to TRUE i.e., expr is not NULL and expr is not 0, the IF function returns the if_true_expr, otherwise it returns if_false_expr. The IF function return a numeric or a string, depending on how it is used.

```
SELECT
    `name`
  , MAX(IF(`rate` = 'one', `rate`, NULL)) some5
  , MAX(IF(`rate` = 'two', `rate`, NULL)) some2
  , MAX(IF(`rate` = 'two', `rate`, NULL)) some3
FROM
  database1
GROUP BY
  name;
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer and format the code. This answer is not only for the OP, the answer should help anybody who reads this thread.

Comment: Table for example. In reality: I have about a hundred "sub" and in  "rate" the user enters the data itself, so that could be anything.  

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this query : SELECT daten, GROUP_CONCAT(sub) as sub FROM table WHERE name= '$name' group by daten. you will get expected output.

Comment: Please explain how this query helps to solve the original problem. Why should the OP use this query? Also please format your code block to help readability. An answer is not just to solve the OP's problem, but it is to help further readers to understand the problem and the solution.